# Is there a way to use more than one LWJGL context

Tags: java, opengl, canvas, lwjgl, display-manager

I am trying to show two displays at the same time, using threads and showing them on 2 different canvas.

Stats of software:

- OS name Linux
- OS version 3.16.0-34-generic
- LWJGL version 2.9.3
- OpenGL version 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3

Code from my GUI Class that I am trying to run:

```
public UIMain2() {
    initComponents();

    canvas1 = new Canvas();
    canvas1.setSize(700, 350);
    canvas1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    canvas1.isDisplayable();
    canvas1.setVisible(true);      
    jPanel2.add(canvas1);      
    dt1 = new DisplayThread(canvas1);
    dt1.start();

    canvas2 = new Canvas();
    canvas2.setSize(700, 350);
    canvas2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    canvas2.isDisplayable();
    canvas2.setVisible(true);      
    jPanel3.add(canvas2);      
    dt2 = new DisplayThread(canvas2);
    dt2.start();
}
```

Sample code of my thread Class:

```
public class DisplayThread extends Thread {

    Canvas canvas;
    String modelString = "";
    Player player;
    Camera camera;
    DisplayManager m;

    public DisplayThread(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void run() {
        m = new DisplayManager();
        m.createDisplayJFrame(canvas);
        ...
    }

    ...

 }
```

Sample code of my DisplayManager Class:

```
public class DisplayManager {

    private static final int WIDTH = 700;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 350;
    private static final int FPS_CAP = 120;

    private static long lastFrameTime;
    private static float delta;

    //Display d = new Display();


    public void createDisplayJFrame(Canvas canvas) {

        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2)
            .withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);

        try {

            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.setParent(canvas);
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
            Display.setTitle("Potato");
        } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
        }
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);   
    }

    ...

}
```

The error that I get is: "Only one LWJGL context may be instantiated at any one time"

Is there a way around this to display the display that each thread makes? At the moment only one canvas shows a display.

Answer (score 1):

LWJGL2 only allows a single display, which is accessed through static methods in the `Display` class. If you wanted to use multiple displays, you would have to upgrade to version 3, where GLFW gives you a better control of your windows.

You could however, as a workaround, use the LWJGL Display and a JFrame with a Canvas. Then you could render into a [framebuffer](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers), get the pixel data with [glGetTexImage](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml) and display it in the canvas.

But because this would not have good performance, and because LWJGL3 is already stable, I recommend that you use the new version.